# How to save a modified data set on SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and was wondering how to save a modified data set on SAS. On my SAS enterprise, there is a dataset called cars on sashelp. I modified the dataset to print only those cars which are from "Acura".

```
proc print data = sashelp.cars;
Where Make="Acura";
run;
```

Now how do I save this modified data set on my WORK library so that I can retrieve it from there and merge it with other data sets and do some more interesting stuff with it. I tried looking for how to do this on Google but wasn't able to find a solution. Would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For purposes of saving SAS data sets, there are two key elements to the below code:

- a `data` statement which instructs SAS where to write the file and what to name it: `data <library>.<table>`. In this case, no library is specified so it will be written to the (default) `work` library. The table will be named `want`.
- a `set` statement which tells you to read the cars table in the sashelp library. One can use the `where` data option to subset the initial table.

```
data want;
set sashelp.cars(where=(make="Acura"));
run;
```